# Calculate percentage covered by green space in a city using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I want to calculate how much percentage of a city district is covered by public green space. I have a city polygon with 10 different city districts and 10 layers showing public green space in different layers. I have also calculated the area of each park and each city district, but not the sum of the parks within the districts.

[image]

Is there an easy way to do this? 
It is also worth mentioning that my aim is to make a thematic map after I have gotten the results.

Comment: Have you had a look at the `statistics` tool? It's represented by the greek E, the sum-smybol.

Comment: If I understood you correctly you could use the merge tool to join your 10 public green space layers and then run an intersection with that layer and the district you are interested in. Once complete you can simply calculate the area of the intersection.

Comment: By 'green' do you mean "Husie", "Rosengard", and "City polygons" altogether? Or you consider one specific green layer?

Comment: @Taras - The layer called city polygons represent the 10 different city districts. The other layers are the actual names of the districts and the polygons in these layers shows public parks/public green space. I want to find out how much of each district is covered with public parks/green space. e.g. Husie 12%, Rosengard 9% and so on.

Comment: @Erik Yes, but not really sure how to use it, I am new to GIS and these kinds of calculations.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the tool Join Attributes By Location in Processing. If you use the Swedish translation (I noticed you are working with Malmö) I think its called "Slå samman attribut efter plats" or something similar, but you can search with the english phrase in processing. Processing is called "Geobearbetning" in the Swedish version.

The process would be:

1. Intersect the parks with the districts, so that you don't count the area of overlapping parks in two districts twice. Use the Intersect tool in processing for this ("Skärning" in Swedish, I think).
2. Calculate the area of the districts to a new attribute in that layer.
3. Calculate the area of the intersected park layer, so that all park slices in the different districts get the correct area.
4. Use Join Attributes By Location to find the Sum of the intersected park area per district.
5. Divide the park area attribute with the sum of the district area attribute in the newly created layer using the Field Calculator to get the percentage.